# php - blank page when using code to connect to data base

Tags: php, mysqli

i get a blank page when using code to connect to a database using php 
even any print statement out side of the connection code is not printed only a blank page  when running the following code

```
<?php

$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '7610', 'sites');
if ($link) {
print "connected";
}
else {  print "faild";}

?>
```

Comment: Have you enabled the error reporting?

Comment: add these lines before your code to check the errors you have
`   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: here is the error that i have got
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Sitestatuse.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Sitestatuse.php on line 4

Comment: thank you all for your concern
i have solve this problem with php.ini file 
the extension directory was not defined 
so i defined it and the code is working right now

Answer (score 1):

Try to use mysqli_connect() instead of mysqli()

Answer (score 0):

Most People agree that PDO offers so much advantages over mysqli functions.... Why not try that Route? You would be glad you did... Here's what a PDO-based version would look like....

```
    <?php

        //DATABASE CONNECTION CONFIGURATION:
        defined("HOST")     or define("HOST",   "localhost");           //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-HOST
        defined("DBASE")    or define("DBASE",  "sites");               //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB NAME
        defined("USER")     or define("USER",   "root");                //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-USER
        defined("PASS")     or define("PASS",   "7610");                //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-PASS

        try {
            $dbh        = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='. DBASE,USER,PASS);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        if($dbh instanceof PDO){
            print "The Coast is clear...";
        }else{
            print "We have a Huge Storm on our hands.... BAIL ;-)";
        }

        // FROM HERE ON, YOU COULD START USING $dbh AS YOUR PDO OBJECT...
        // FOR EXAMPLE YOU COULD DO A SELECT LIKE SO:           
        $sql        = 'SELECT u.* FROM user AS u';
        $stmt       = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result     = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        var_dump($result);
```